# How to add padding around a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

The following LaTeX code is saved in the file `~\test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1][1-2]
\tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\lipsum[1-1][3-4]

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~\test.tex`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: A TikZ picture inside a paragraph.]

I'd like to add space around the picture. I tried to do so by adding `[inner sep=1cm]` or `[outer sep=1cm]` just after `\tikz`, but neither alternative had any visible effect on the outcome.

Note that the example above is a watered down minimal working version of the TikZ picture I am actually interested in, so the solution must be general.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As I mentioned in the last sentence, the example above is a watered down version. For one, the TikZ picture I am interested in is embedded in an article, and I'm only interested in adding the space around a certain TikZ picture inside this article.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK. Will do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've changed it per your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inner` and `outer sep` applies to nodes.

There are various ways of doing this by drawing (invisible) paths relative to the bounding box of the diagram. TikZ defines a node called `current bounding box` which at any given point surrounds the contents of the diagram that is drawn up to that point, so you can use that. Here are two examples, the first one uses no libraries, the second one the `fit` library.

Obviously the additional code has to be the *last* thing in the diagram, before `\end{tikzpicture}`/the closing brace in `\tikz{}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
    \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,1);\path (current bounding box.south west) +(-1,-1) (current bounding box.north east) +(1,1);}
\lipsum*[1]
    \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,1);\node[fit=(current bounding box), inner sep=1cm]{};}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Addendum:

You can apply this to *all* `tikzpicture`s in a document with the `every picture` style and `execute at end picture`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}

\tikzset{
every picture/.style={
  execute at end picture={
    \path (current bounding box.south west) +(-1,-1) (current bounding box.north east) +(1,1);
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
\tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,1);}
\lipsum*[1]
\tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,1);}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Please note that I've changed my post per David Carlisle's comments, so that I no longer use the `standalone` document type. Would you please revise your answer accordingly?

Comment: @EvanAad It doesn't really matter, as this approach doesn't care about the documentclass, but sure ...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to altering `current bounding box`, you can use `backgrounds` library and fix the `background` rectangle for the whole `tikzpicture`.

The option `inner frame sep` adds some padding around the picture and options `framed`(or `show background rectangle`) draw the picture border which can also not drawn with `background rectangle/.style={draw=none}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1][1-2]
\tikz[background rectangle/.style={draw=none}, 
    inner frame sep=5mm, 
    framed
    ]{ \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,1);}
\lipsum[1-1][3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]